# Strange Pixel Shifting / Jumping in Firefox with CSS Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### The Problem:

I'm using CSS to make a card flip around and show a kitten. There is a behavior that seems to only exist in Firefox whereby it is constantly shifting / resizing the images by a few pixels. Simply hover over the card back and watch as it moves around a little ***after*** the scale animation completes, then flip the card by clicking on it to observe how the kitten readjust its position and size after the animation as well.

Again, this does not happen in Chrome nor Internet Explorer. Can anyone explain what is causing it or provide a remedy?

### The Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XEDEM/1/

### The Code:

```
$('.card').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1.2)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1.2)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms',
        '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 500ms'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'transform': 'scale(1)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'scale(1)',
        'transition': 'transform 500ms',
        '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 500ms'
    });
}).mousedown(function() {
    $('div.back').css({
        'transform': 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg) translateZ(0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(-180deg)',
        'transition': 'transform 800ms ease-in-out 300ms',
        '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 800ms ease-in-out 300ms'
    });
    $('.hide').show();
    $('div.front').css({
        'transform': 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(0) translateZ(0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'perspective(1000px) rotateY(0)',
        'transition': 'transform 800ms ease-in-out 300ms',
        '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 800ms ease-in-out 300ms',
        'backface-visibility': 'hidden',
        '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden'
    });
});
```

Comment: Not reproducible in ``FX [33.0a1 (2014-07-03)] for Mac``

Comment: Installed latest Nightly (33.0a1) on a second computer (PC); still occurs. Absolutely reproducible. Also occurs via BrowserStack.com testing, so it's not limited to my setups. Evidently you guys just don't see what it is I'm referring to. You have to compare it to Chrome because it's a very subtle effect that occurs after the animation completes. The images are moved and resized ever-so-slightly (by about 1 pixel).

Comment: For even more proof, observe its behavior without the scaling effect applied. The problem disappears. http://jsfiddle.net/XEDEM/3/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some ardent research, this is a **[known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176)** with Firefox's sub-pixel rendering. More obvious demonstrations of the effect can be found [here](http://codepen.io/MattyBalaam/details/eaJto) and [here](http://episode17.com/public/flockr/). The phenomenon is referred to as "pixel snapping" and it occurs rather frequently in Firefox's animation, particularly at the conclusion of a transition.

The solution, which is also proposed in the Bugzilla thread, is to add `rotate(0.0001deg)` to the scaling transform. This greatly reduces the effect but does not entirely eliminate it. However, it is the best I can hope for, so I'm accepting it as the answer.

Comment: You should avoid rants about voting in answers but instead post them as a comment on the question

Comment: Had the same issue when using css opacity on images while hovering. Rotate solved it. Thanks dude.

Comment: This seems to have the added bonus of making the entire transition smoother in Edge too.

Comment: I can't believe in 2018 this is still an issue.  I'm working on an animation that involves a number or rotations so I can't use the provided solution / hack (which I do know solves some of the problems). In the age of modern web development the fact Firefox haven't sorted this is a disgrace.